# What was the informational content of the universe at the Planck time?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, quantum-information, entropy, big-bang

If the energy of [$1 \, \mathrm{bit}$ of information](https://physicsworld.com/a/information-converted-to-energy/) [is $k_{\small{\text{B}}}T \ln{2}$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6052), then the energy of that bit increases with the temperature of the system. When I try to calculate how much energy 1 bit of information would have had around the Planck time, when the temperature of the universe was in the ballpark of [${10}^{32}\,\mathrm{K}$ and the diameter was around ${10}^{-33}\,\mathrm{cm}$](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/BBhistory.html), then the energy of that $1\,\mathrm{bit}$ of information is suspiciously close to the [Bekenstein bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound). In fact, the result I got was $1.3719436998375747 ,$ which **I think** means that the energy of $1\,\mathrm{bit}$ of information at planck time was just a bit less than would have been required to collapse the universe into a black hole before it had even begun (perhaps even before inflation could save it from said fate).

Is it just coincidence that the number I happen to get is so close to the Bekenstein bound? Was the Information (or entropy or negentropy or whatever you want to call it) contained in the big bang really THAT low? I mean, I knew it had to be low, but 1 bit seems to be cutting things a bit fine, doesn't it?

Comment: I suspect there is some circularity to your calculation: the Planck time is effectively defined as (the ball park) time when the energy density is such that quantum gravity kicks in and the Berkenstein Bound is reached.

Comment: Lol! You might well be right... Still though, any idea how many bits of information would have come with the Big Bang? If the universe had a finite size and a finite volume and a finite temperature, then we should be able to calculate the energy (on that note, I can't believe I didn't do that last night...). What is that figure and how does it compare to the 1 bit =  956992961.692908J  I got in my calculation.

Comment: I think you can only study information-of-universe questions from the other end starting with the known observable universe. Check out https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35920/maximum-possible-information-in-the-universe

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I'll definitely check out that thread. I still think there's something to my question though... Ultimately, all the information that exists in today's universe evolved from the informational content of the universe at the time of the big bang. And, following that, there's the question of how much information will exist at the final moment of the universe? The temperature will be MUCH lower, but will the temperature ever get low enough that once again only 1 bit of information will exist? What does that total information content curve look like?

Comment: Big bang may be not the exact picture. This is to say the expansion of the baby universe is not really an explosion of a certain system, instead it's a expansion just like an empire conquers more countries.  I believe the inflation is the process of the establishment of entanglement among qubits just as the scrambling time of black holes, which glues tiny space patches and construct geometry by entangling more qubits just like evolving a product state to an entangled state.

Comment: X. Dong, that's an interesting take on things... You're suggesting that inflation **is** the establishment of entanglement among qubits? Where did the qubits come from? Did they come from the "conquering empire" or were they spontaneously generated? Are the qubits entangled only with qubits within our universe or are they also entangled with qubits from the aforementioned conquering empire?

Comment: @Thor No idea where the qubits come from. If the slogan 'spacetime is built by entanglement' is true, then big bang creates spacetime by entangling qubits. At least L. Susskind pointed out complexity=volume, so the 'bang and expansion' is related with quantum complexity.  Not sure the big bang starting from a product state or not, maybe a phase transition can also work (multi-phase = multiverse?), this sounds like the collision of branes.

Comment: @Thor At least I saw two pictures from the information point of view. One is the quantum graphity where the big bang is described as decreasing the degrees of a complete graph of qubits(it corresponds to a space with a radius of a plank length). The second picture is what I described, where expansion is to entangle more qubits. Quantum graphity is strange since to build that complete graph is difficult from the complexity side. Not only we need to care about the qubits(nodes of the graph), also we have to answer how they were connected, the edges. This is more difficult than my picture.

Comment: What is the point of 17 digits of accuracy?

Comment: @Jens - Implied precision?

Comment: A result can only be as precise as the least precise input value. Which values and formula did you use? An overly large number of decimals shows a misunderstanding of error propagation. That's the polite version of a certain quote :-)

Comment: @Jens - Yeah, yeah, yeah, I know, I know. You're right of course :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Was the Information (or entropy or negentropy or whatever you want to
> call it) contained in the big bang really THAT low?

Yes, the entropy of an observable universe must [start](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3983) low. So, **how low?**

1. The history of the universe can be modelled [based](https://darkmatterdarkenergy.com/2016/11/26/dark-gravity-is-gravity-thermodynamic/) on just 3 energy density parameters: i) density during inflation, ii) density at radiation – matter equilibrium, and iii) dark energy density at late epochs.
2. Padmanabhan ([2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2284)), using these 3 densities, showed that the cosmological constant problem can be solved within the emergent gravity paradigm if one could attribute a value $4π$ to the measure of degrees of freedom in the universe at the Planck epoch.

**TLDR:** The above implies that the entropy of the cosmic event horizon of the Universe at the [Hot](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132794/is-the-big-bang-defined-as-before-or-after-inflation/141474#141474) Big Bang  (end of inflation) was **$4\pi$ nats.** So low, yes, but more than 1 bit.

Comment: Holographic equipartition! I love it! But that's 4π nats at the end of inflation, right? I suppose that asking what the entropy/information value would have been at the very first  unit of Planck time is actually a pretty silly question now that I think about it... The entropy at the end of inflation is much more relevant to our current predicament.